# K500 keyboard on Arch Linux (cedilha)

Tags: keyboard, arch-linux

I use a K500 keyboard on Arch Linux, I usually type the cedilha on Windows, Ubuntu and Mac by typing the ' key and then the c key. In Arch Linux (using I3) until today I couldn't do the same behavior. Note: I'm using the us layout.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I already managed to solve my problem, in this case it was for the K500 mechanical keyboard on Arch Linux using I3, but I think it also works for Keycron keyboard and several other keyboards.

I don't know why, but it took many hours for me to figure this out, and other distros didn't even need effort.

Just edit the i3 configuration file (~/.config/i3/config) and put at the end:

```
exec --no-startup-id setxkbmap -layout us -variant intl
```

Obs. I'm just posting the solution to help those who went through the same problem.